# rake ts:rebuild doesn't work as a crontab task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, sphinx

```
0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/rails/xxx/releases/20110105175853 && RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:rebuild --silent'
```

hi, guys. this is a crontab task generated by whenever. it's rebuilding the sphinx index.
 it doesn't work when it run as a crontab task, with no error in the /var/log/cron log. but  it works when I run the command manually.

anybody can help? thank you very much.

Comment: getting all the string escaping correct for making cron happy is a pain.  I would suggest taking your bash runline and making it into a little bash script.  Then you can just put that one simple runline in your crontab file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cron task looks alittle bizarre to me. Not sure that you want to be calling ts:rebuild all the time, you only need to rebuild if your server gets rebooted, to update the index you just run ts:index, below is the cron task I use for my rails app, it refreshes the sphinx index every 5 minutes.

if your using the user crontab this should work:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/appuser/rails-app; RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:index >> /dev/null
```

if your putting your crons in /etc/cron.d/ you will need to add the username, like this:

```
*/5 * * * * appuser cd /home/appuser/rails-app; RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:index >> /dev/null
```

These settings are for an Ubuntu box, but should work with most linux distros.

Hope this helps.